# regex selecting columns that contain string except one

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a  `pandas` DataFrame as shown below. I want to select all columns that end with "_cd" or "_ind" except for the column "final_ind". How can I do that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'var1': [20, 30.0, 40],
  'var2_ind': ["a4", "a3", "b1"],
  'var3_cd': [10, 5, 7],
  'final_ind': [1, 0, 1],
})
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
df.ix[:, df.columns.str.contains('_cd|_ind')] #Gets all columns except var1
df.ix[:, df.columns.str.contains('_cd|_ind[^final_ind]')] #Gets only var3_cd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` with `regex` like so:

```
df.filter(regex='^(?!final).*(_cd|_ind)$')

# var2_ind  var3_cd
#0      a4       10
#1      a3        5
#2      b1        7
```

---

- `^(?!final)` will assert the column names don't start with `final` thanks to negative look ahead *`(?!...)`*;
- `.*(_cd|_ind)$` matches column names ending with `_cd` or `_ind`;

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without using `negative look ahead RegEx`:

```
In [24]: df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('(?:_cd|_ind)$')].drop('final_ind')]
Out[24]:
  var2_ind  var3_cd
0       a4       10
1       a3        5
2       b1        7
```